# DirectX11 Setup error

Tags: directx

I have Frank D Lunas directx11 book, and i'm trying to set it up using VS2012, but i've run into this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FirstProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: "C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Applications\DirectX\Utilities\bin\x64\fxc.exe /nologo /Emain /Fo "C:\Users\Josh\Documents\DirectX\Chapter 1\Projects\FirstProject\Debug\color.cso" /Od /Zi FX\color.fx". The handle is invalid.
1>  
1>  
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and I have no idea how to fix it.

I believe I have all the paths correct, and included files.

Any ideas?

Thanks!